# 2 COM objects and using interface from one of it in another

Tags: c#, c++, interface, com, parameter-passing

I have following setup:

C# app and two COM objects (Face AND Processor), written in C++.
First COM object exposes interface IFace. It is described in its IDL file.
Second COM object has an interface IProcessor, exposing method ProcessFace(IFace* face).

And C# app should use first COM object to get face and second to process it.
question here is - what is correct way to write IDL file for second object so it can consume parameters of interface type from first COM.

Should i somehow include face.idl into processor.idl or just leave this parameter as void* and then cast it to IFace* in ProcessFace implementation?

Am i right that second COM object should include some .h files from first one (for interface sharing), but this is the only thing it should include?

Comment: couldn't you put all that c++ in one .idl file (with forward declaration)?

Comment: @SimonMourier no unfortunately. the have different way of working. one is exemodule which spawns separate process for each usage of main com object. and other is dll. the architecture is rather cumbersome, i tried to simplify while asking, for sake of brevity

Comment: That is an essential detail.  One of the interface pointers has to always be marshalled since its server runs out-of-process, you can't marshal a void*.  Don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here -- `import` or `importlib`.

Unfortunately, `import` causes interface and coclass definitions from the imported file to be present in the compiled `.tlb` file. This causes all sorts of issues at registration and proxying time. I do not recommend using `import`.

`importlib` doesn't suffer from this same problem. However, this means you have to compile the `.idl` to a `.tlb` first, before you can import it. Compile a `.tlb` from the `.idl` that contains your dependency (`IFace`). Then reference that type library from the `.idl` that contains your dependent (`IProcessor`) using the [`importlib`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367050(v=vs.85).aspx) keyword. Your second `.idl` file will look something like this:

```
[...]
library ProcessorLibrary
{
    importlib("FaceLibrary.tlb");

    [...]
    interface IProcessor
    {
        HRESULT ProcessFace(FaceLibrary.IFace* face)
    };
}
```

For the `importlib` argument, you can use either a fully-qualified path or a relative path. If you use a relative path, it will try to resolve this filename using your `PATH` environment variable. If you are using Visual Studio for this, you can set the search path in the project properties -- under `VC++ Directories`, put your search path into the `Executable Directories` variable. This corresponds to the `ExecutablePath` property in the `.vcxproj` file.

Note that the "`FaceLibrary`" in the `importlib` and in the interface are different. The one in `importlib` is the name of the `.tlb` file. The identifier used in the interface is the type library name (the name you used with the `library` key in the first `.idl` file).

In order to compile the generated C++ for the second `.idl` file, you have to do two things. The first `.tlb` needs to be manually `#import`ed into the second C++ project, just as you had to use `importlib` in the second `.idl`. Then you need to deal with C++ namespace issues. Unfortunately, `midl.exe` doesn't produce code that uses namespaces. Although the second `.idl` file contains `FaceLibrary.IFace`, the generated C++ just contains `IFace`. This means that you need to either import the first `.tlb` into the C++ project using no namespaces, or you have to use a typedef.

Using no namespaces:

```
#import "FaceLibrary.tlb" no_namespace
#include "Processor_i.h"
```

Using namespaces:

```
#import "FaceLibrary.tlb"
typedef FaceLibrary.IFace IFace;
#include "Processor_i.h"
```

The resolution of relative paths in `#import` works the same way as in `importlib`.

Comment: i'll try. should .tlb be copied to folder of Processor project? or could it be referenced just by name?

Comment: well, idl got compiled, but now it complains about IFace in Processor_i.h  
  
`/* [in] */ /* external definition not present */ IFace *face,`

Comment: Ah, yes. This is, IMO, a bug in midl.exe. I'll update my answer on how to address this.

Comment: @Demo_S Any luck?

Comment: not really. i'm trying different options, and still doesn't work. i can't figure out, where should i put these lines with 'typedef FaceLibrary.IFace IFace  
#include "Processor_i.h"  

i also have one working example with importlib, but can't do in same way. actually doing in same way causes error in my solution and works in example

Comment: Somewhere in your second C++ project, you're already #include-ing Processor_i.h. The error you show above is proof of that. Just search for "Processor_i.h". And then add the two lines shown above.

Comment: ok thanks a lot! you advices are really helpful. I moved couple steps further. though have to put 'import ' in several places. However now it complains about `missing ) before *` and `'IFace': name in formal parameter is illegal` near IFace in c-style interface of Processor_i.h  
  
`/* [id] */ HRESULT ( STDMETHODCALLTYPE *TrackFace )( 
            ITestObject * This,
            /* [in] */ /* external definition not present */ IFace **face,
            /* [retval][out] */ int *result);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the idl [import](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367047.aspx) directive. The Windows SDK .idl files is full of these (like `import "unknwn.idl";`). So, in `processor.idl`:

```
import "face.idl";  

[
    object,
    uuid(6E0537CC-232A-4E73-A625-358591CA9231),
    pointer_default(unique)
]
interface IProcessor
{
    HRESULT ProcessFace(IFace *pFace);
};
```

Of course, this will need the .idl files (and generated .h and various artifacts, if any, for compilation phase) to be present in accessible directories.

Comment: The problem with `import` is that is causes interface and coclass definitions from the imported file to be included in the compiled `.tlb`. This introduces all sorts of registration and proxying problems.

Comment: I created a sample set of files if you'd like to fact check me on this one. Just download these files and run `build.cmd` from a Visual Studio command prompt. Then take a look at the `.tlb` files using `oleview.exe`. You'll see that `IFoo` exists in `BarLib.tlb`. This means `BarLib.tlb` would become the official type library, if it were ever to be registered using `RegisterTypeLib`. https://gist.github.com/mgunter6/8d30a23bd64a576118253fb157dcabaf

Comment: @MichaelGunter - both options are valid, it really depends how you want to define your idl. You don't necessarily need to put interfaces in the typelib (under the typelib attribute). You can use interfaces in C# w/o a tlb (although it's more initial work). Hence my initial question on putting everything in the same file. If idl files have an intimate knowledge of each other, it could be logical to define only one tlb and every project references it (whatever the deployment constraints are). Otherwise, they can use IIDs and IUnknown pointers, which is also a very common pattern within the SDK.